# How to I force a bluetooth connection with a paired device while that device is currently connected with another paired device?

Tags: bluetooth

I have 3 jellybean devices (xoom, N7, & GNex) all paired with a single set of bluetooth headphones (Sony DR-BT21G).  Occasionally I get settled in with a device to watch netflix, only to find that my headphones are currently connected to the last used device in another room.  Right now I have to get up and find the other device and either shut it off, or manually disconnect the bluetooth connection with the headphones before I can manually connect with the device I want to use.  Seems pretty clumsy, especially when I'm feeling exceptionally lazy.

So.. How can I tell the device I'm holding to just "take over" the connection, forcing the other device to disconnect?